# a software which transfers erd to database tables automatically

Tags: database-design

i have drawn an er diagram for a database projecta dn i need a software which transfers this drawing to tables. would you pleaseintroduce me a good software which helps me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Several products do this, [Sybase Power Designer](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner) will do this, [ERwin](http://www.erwin.com/) will do this also. There are others

Answer (score 1):

Do it yourself, by hand, carefully choosing your data types, indexes etc...
I don't think automated options give a result you would be proud of. I even doubt the other ways would give you a correct working result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio to diagram your database and generate the db code for you. The diagram will be stored in SQL Server itself so will respond to changes made elsewhere.

One of the flavors of Microsoft Visio can do this for SQL Server.  (It used to be 2003 Enterprise Architect, I'm not sure what it is these days.)

[MySQL WorkBench](http://wb.mysql.com/) will do it for MySQL.

Of course you'll need to redraw your diagram with the tool.